# Cookie gets deleted on restarting browser

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies, setcookie

The cookie which i set in codeigniter gets deleted after i restart the browser. I'm setting up a cookie like:

```
$test_cookie = array(
                    'name'=>'test',
                    'value'=> 'test',
                    'expire'=> time() + 60*60*24*14
                );

$this->input->set_cookie($test_cookie);
```

The `print_r($test_cookie)` returns:

```
Array ( [name] => test [value] => test [expire] => 1309943188 )
```

Now i can print the cookie to make sure that the cookie is set:

```
$test_cookie= $this->input->cookie('test');
echo "<b> Cookie value: </b>". $test_cookie;
```

The cookie prints the value correctly.

However, if i restart the browser, i don't get the cookie value anymore. I've tried multiple browsers. With the `var_dump`, i get: `bool(false)` 
Why the cookie is getting deleted when browser restarts?

Thanks.

Comment: Is some setting in your browser automatically deleting cookies at shutdown? Does it happens with every browser?

Comment: @Damien Pirsy as i mentioned i have trued multiple browsers, and its happening with all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CodeIgniter documentation says the `expires` value is added to the current time. So effectively the `expires` value in your case is `time() + time() + 60*60*24*14`. This may be beyond the 32 Bit integer limit and turn into a negative value. This in turn will result in a temporary cookie that's deleted upon closing the browser.

```
$test_cookie = array(
  'name'=>'test',
  'value'=> 'test',
  'expire'=> 60*60*24*14
);
```

should work. I think.

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly the problem was.